# Chrome: Any way to assign sticky window name as a title

Tags: google-chrome

I use ubuntu 22.04. I have named my chrome tabs (via [Chrome: Any way to assign sticky window name](https://superuser.com/questions/908196/chrome-any-way-to-assign-sticky-window-name)), but they only show up when I am selecting windows from the task bar.

Is there any way to have the window name be visible while I am browsing the window? For example it could be a title on the top bar, or above the window?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is go to

1. Settings
2. Appearance
3. Use System Title and borders

click this option to on and a new border will appear with the title.